# How many String objects will be created here?

Tags: java, string

```
String x = new String("xyz");
String y = "abc"; 
x = x + y;
```

How many `String` objects would get created in this code?

Comment: Please tell us how you derive the idea that there would be two objects.

Comment: 3, and I vote for close.

Comment: Three.  Strings are immutable, so reassignment creates another String.

Comment: Silly interview question. It's not specified.

Comment: @RTA - The reason people are "arguing" is that this is an **ambiguous** question.  Which is what makes it silly.  It also doesn't have a single correct answer because it depends on behaviours which could (and in one case does) vary depending on the JVM you are using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There will be at least four objects:

- The interned string `"xyz"`
- The copy of the interned `"xyz"` string
- The interned string `"abc"`
- The result of concatenating the two strings.

Comment: `x+y` will evaluate to 'xyzabc' .This object will be stored in The `String Pool`. And then `new String("xyzabc");` will be called resulting in a string object on heap,whose reference is returned to `x`. So there are 5 objects. My answer is based on the `public String(String original) constructor code` [from this reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 7):

```
String x = new String("xyz");
```

There's one: `"xyz"` is an interned string.
There's two: `new String("xyz")`.

```
String y = "abc";
```

There's three: `"abc"` is an interned string.

```
x = x + y;
```

There's four. Since strings are immutable a third string object must be created: `new String("xyzabc")`.

It's possible there could be a fifth object, because the compiler could use a StringBuilder to perform string concatenation.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(x);
s.append(y);
x = s.toString();
```

Comment: But is the backing `char[]` shared between `StringBuilder` and `String`. It's a nonsense question.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline.  1) I think that depends on the version of Java, doesn't it?  2) Yes it is ... kind of.

Answer (score 6):

When the class is loaded, two String objects are created (most likely), one for each String literal.  This is a one-time thing ...

Each time the code is run, two Strings are created:

- The `new String("xyz")` creates a new String whose state is the same as the `"xyz"` literal.
- The String concatenation `x + y` creates a second new String.

It should be noted that `String y = "abc";` does NOT create a new String.  Rather, it assigns the reference to an existing String to `y`.  In fact, it is the reference to the String object for the literal that was created when the class was loaded.

---

Actually, if you drill down, there is going to be a `char[]` array created for each of the String objects created.  And the String concatenation *may* involve the creation of a temporary `StringBuilder` object.  Both of these are implementation details.

It is also possible that loading the class *might* not result in *creation* of new String objects.  It is true that the String literals will be represented by String Objects in the string pool, however the exact process of how that happens is an implementation detail ... and it doesn't *necessarily* entail calling `String.intern` on a freshly created String object.

---

And yet another answer is that ZERO objects get created.  That is just Java source code, and Java source code doesn't create objects unless you compile it and run it.  (Tada!!)

Comment: It's not "xyz" literal, but "abc"

Comment: @fazomisiek - I don't understand what you are saying.  (I think you may have misread what I wrote ...)

Answer (score 1):

x : as you are using the new keyword and constructor of the class String a String object is created

"abc": is a string literal and Java creates a String object whenever it encounters a string literal.

x : the concatenation of two strings is transformed to StringBuilder.append(X).append(Y).toString(), so another object is created here.